# EC2 Instance Type for NetData Master?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, monitoring, netdata

I am currently working on monitoring my EC2 Instances on AWS.

I already installed NetData on a Master Instance that receives information from Slaves Instances, all is working find on that point.

NetData default history is set to 36000 seconds.
At the moment, only 4 nodes are streaming to the Master, every 15 seconds.

The Master Instance started with a t3.medium type (ambitious, I know!)
It RAM approached 100% in a few minutes.
I upgraded it to t3.large.

Tomorrow, 8 more nodes will come in production and stream on Master Instance.

Does anyone know an Instance Type that is optimised for this use case or any recommendations?

Thanks.